# Change window onload to work after pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JQuery which works on initial page load:

```
  $(window).on('load', function(){
    $('.details').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.description').stop().animate({
      height: "toggle",
      opacity: "toggle"
    }, 200);
  });
});
```

Now that I have added pagination and filters to the page, the window onload obviously won't work once any pagination or filters have been triggered. I understand that I need to create an additional function to ensure the above will still work, however I believe that there is something not write with my code, as when pagination is used, I am still getting no jquery. I am using the correct approach?

This is what I have so far:

```
 document.onreadystatechange = function(){
if (document.readyState === "complete") {
  $('.details').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.description').stop().animate({
      height: "toggle",
      opacity: "toggle"
    }, 200);
  });
}
else {
   window.onload = function () {
    $('.details').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.description').stop().animate({
      height: "toggle",
      opacity: "toggle"
    }, 200);
  });
   };
  };
 }
```

I am still learning.

Comment: This is where functions come in handy. Make a function and call it from both places

Answer (score 0):

Created a function (partA), and then triggered function when required (partB)

```
  // PART A
function cardFunction(){
    $('.details').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.description').stop().animate({
      height: "toggle",
      opacity: "toggle"
    }, 300);
  });
}

// PART B
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  cardFunction();
});
```